# PHP serving image from outside of webroot

Tags: php, image, header, readfile

Today I was working on my website's function.php in an area that had nothing to do with serving images.  I have a php script which gets images from outside of the webroot and serves them based on $_GET for the moment.  One minute it was working and then the next it was not. I have no idea what happened. I chalked it up to MAC Sierra's BS server management but moving everything to a LINUX server made no difference.

```
    <?php
    include('includes/functions.php');  
    $path = $privatePath;
    $uid = getUserProfileImage();
    $img = $_GET['img'];    
    $file = $path."/img/users/".$uid."/".$img; 
    $fallback = "img/site/login.png"; 

    //DETERMINE TYPE 
    $var = explode ('.', $img);
    $ext = array_pop($var); 
    $allowed['gif'] = 'image/gif'; 
    $allowed['png'] = 'image/png'; 
    $allowed['jpg'] = 'image/jpeg'; 
    $allowed['jpeg'] = 'image/jpeg'; 

    if(file_exists($file) && $ext != '' && isset($allowed[strToLower($ext)])) { 
        $type = $allowed[strToLower($ext)]; 
    } else { 
        $file = $fallback; 
        $type = 'image/png'; 
    } 

    header('Content-Type: '.$type);
    //header ("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"{$img}\");
    header("Content-length: ".(string)(filesize($file)));  
    //echo file_get_contents($file);
    readfile($file); 
    exit(); 

?>
```

This code was working just fine a from one min to the next. I have checked the permissions of the folder and verify that it is owned by www-data. Firefox reveals that the image has an error. Usually I had that error message when I was echoing something before the output buffer. But now it is for who knows what reason.

The RAW Data output in Firefox is as such when reading the image:

```
CgoKCv/Y/+EeQUV4aWYAAElJKgAIAAAADAAAAQMAAQAAAAACAAABAQMAAQAAAAACAAACAQMAAwAAAJ4AAAAGAQMAAQAAAAIAAAASAQMAAQAAAAEAAAAVAQMAAQAAAAMAAAAaAQUAAQAAAKQAAAAbAQUAAQAAAKwAAAAoAQMAAQAAAAIAAAAxAQIAHgA ...
```

And that goes on for a bit. I have resaved the image and about everything else that I can think of. I have even deleted all work done from prior when the script worked and no change. Anyone got any ideas? Or is there more error that I can log to see the problem and get a hint?

Comment: The path you want to access for images from outside the document root comes is the relative path to the document root path? I mean, for example, if your document root path is like `/var/www/html/` and the path you serve images from is like `/var/www/images` or `/var/images` or something like that following the same top root path `/var`? You mean like that?

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists?

Comment: Absolutely. It is no matter what the filename is, the results are the same. I have also verified the file types and even resaved them, however the script handles several types

Comment: As far as the path goes, the path is correct or Firefox would not return an error stating the image has errors.

Comment: Best I can tell, the code is fine. I did not change it. The server changed or something. Or in a previous function, there is some kind of output that is interrupting this script. I can not see how it is possible, but I also can not explain how it breaks when I was not even working on it.